# Delete an Object Using Object Property in Firebase (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to delete a record where I don't have its path/key but I've its object property for example:

I've record in database like:

```
slots {
  slot 1 : {
     bookings: [
       objectPath : {
         bookingID: "adadasd"
       }    
     ]
  }
}
```

and I want to delete a single object from bookings array `where bookingID === "adadasd"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete a document, you must know its full path.  If you don't know the path, you must first query for the document using the fields you know (for you, bookingID), then delete the document using ID in the snapshot of the document that your query found.  There is not a single command to run that does both - Firestore does not offer an equivalent to a SQL "delete where" command.